# Notification onClick to other fragment

Tags: java, android

I would like to display the status of notification depending on order status changes. As of now, i am able to display it. Now the next task is that when user clicks on notification, I prefer to take this to the track order fragment where the user can see his order status in detail.

Here is my code:

```
  public static void createNotification(FragmentActivity activity, boolean isLoggedIn, String selectedOrderId, String order_status, String status_desc)
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Lugmah Order Status")
                    .setContentText("The Order Status of Order Id: "+selectedOrderId+ "is: "+status_desc)
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;


        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(activity, TrackOrderFragment.class);
        targetIntent.putExtra("isTrackOrder", false);
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(activity);

        if(isLoggedIn)
        {
            if(status_desc.equals("Rejected"))
            {
                targetIntent.putExtra("isLoggedIn", true);
                targetIntent.putExtra("status_desc", status_desc);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                bundle.putString("status_desc", status_desc);
                bundle.putString("selectedOrderId", selectedOrderId);
                targetIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(TrackOrderFragment.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(targetIntent);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            targetIntent.putExtra("isLoggedIn", false);
        }
        PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

And I would like to pass the data that is **Status_desc and SelectedOrderId** between two fragments.

To receive data, here is the code I wrote.

```
status_desc = getArguments().getString("status_desc");
        rejectedOrderId = getArguments().getString("rejectedOrderId");
```

Here the I am getting notification when admin changes order status. But, I am not able to navigate to **TrackOrderFragment.class** onClick of Notification.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code on button click

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = new tasks();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The thing here is im getting notification. onclicking that notification ,I would go to next activity.

Answer (score 0):

May be doing 
`Intent targetIntent = new Intent(activity, TrackOrderActivity.class);` instead of `Intent targetIntent = new Intent(activity, TrackOrderFragment.class);` would help you. You may send a flag as intent extra to know whether the activity is created from notification. Attach the fragment with that activity.

Comment: The name of the fragment is TrackOrderFragment.class. I believe There is something missing to pass data between two fragements

Answer (score 0):

I was mainly talking about this code block.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Lugmah Order Status")
                .setContentText("The Order Status of Order Id: "+selectedOrderId+ "is: "+status_desc)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;


    Intent targetIntent = new Intent(activity, TrackOrderActivity.class);
    targetIntent.putExtra("isTrackOrder", false);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    if(isLoggedIn)
    {
        if(status_desc.equals("Rejected"))
        {
            targetIntent.putExtra("isFromNotification", true);
            bundle.putString("status_desc", status_desc);
            bundle.putString("sejectedOrderId", selectedOrderId);
            targetIntent.putExtra("orderBundle",bundle);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        targetIntent.putExtra("isLoggedIn", false);
    }

    //PendingIntent 
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        targetIntent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

   NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Now inside of the TrackOrderActivity onCreate method do this.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_order);
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromNotification",true)){
      TrackOrderFragment fragment = new TrackOrderFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getBundleExtra("orderBundle"));

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
       replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
}
```

Now on your TrackOrderFragment if you call getArguments() I think you will get your bundle data.